# Storing NSNumber in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

I have the following declarations in my model.h:

```
@interface Model: NSObject {
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
....
}
@property (nonatomic) double myDouble;
```

The corresponding @synthesize in model.m:

```
@synthesize myDouble;
```

I then have the following setter override:

```
-(void) setMyDouble: (double) newDouble{
myDouble = newDouble;
[myMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]];
}
```

Putting a break point after the array assignment, the debugger shows the following for myMutableArray:

> myMutableArray = (_NSArrayM *) 0x631c450 1 objects
>
> 0 = (NSCFNumber *) 0x631c6a0

So, my double does not seem to be properly getting into the array.  I have subsequent assignments to this array for NSStrings that show up fine in the debugger.  The values for both myDouble and newDouble are good (usually just an integer).

I've read several threads on assigning doubles to NSMutableArrays and haven't discovered anything out of the ordinary.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

**Update**

It appears that the code is correct, but I failed to understand that the debugger shows the NSNumber's address rather than its value.  Thank you everyone for responding, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Correct me if I overlook something, but your debugger output shows that there *is* an NSNumber in your array. So what's the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  In the typical debugging scenario, myDouble will be a single integer, say the number 9.  The debugger shows myDouble as 9, but shows the myMutableArray entry as above.

Comment: Don't mistake the address of the NSNumber object for its value.

Comment: @Michael how do you call setMyDouble function ? Can you plz post code regarding that if you don't mind.

Comment: @Jennis - I am calling setMyDouble from within an IBAction in my view controller when a digit is pressed.  Sorry, I don't have the code at the moment.

Comment: @Eiko - so the 0 = (NSCFNumber *) 0x631c6a0 is saying the address of the NSNumber is 0x631c6a0? If I store an NSString of, say "Hello" at the second position of the array, the debugger shows "Hello."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are confusing with `0` in `0 = (NSCFNumber *) 0x631c6a0`. That 0 is the index of the NSNumber in the array. If you retrieve the objects from the array and print it in NSLog, it would show you the correct values. Nothing seems to be wrong in your code.

Comment: @EmptyStack - thanks for responding.  I am aware that the first index of the array is 0.  My expectation is that the debugger would show the same value for the array as for the value of myDouble, which when I test is usually a single-digit integer, typically 9.

Comment: @Michael you're expecting too much from the debugger. Are you, perhaps, a former Visual Studio user? :)

Comment: @ageektrapped - That would be a revelation! :) So how should I interpret this entry from the debugger: myMutableArray = (_NSArrayM *) 0x631c450 1 objects

0 = (NSCFNumber *) 0x631c6a0

Comment: Just like EmptyStack says in the answer, it's the index of the NSArray. To see the value of the NSNumber, you could try 'p (double)[[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]' in the debugger

Comment: Oh, and I am learning Visual Studio/C# at work and learning Xcode and Objective-C at home just for fun.

Comment: @ageektrapped, OMG!! Are you a prophet? ;-)

Comment: @ageektrapped - so what is the 0x631c6a0 ?  The value of myDouble (as shown in the debugger) is 9.

Comment: @Michael Mangold, That should be the address of the object(NSNumber)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to allocate your mutable array. Debug your app and see if the array is allocated or not.

**Edit**

Change your function name to something else and see the magic.

Comment: Whoops, should have mentioned that I have overridden the init method:- (id) init {
myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return self;
}